# UIButton height constraint swift not working

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

So I have this UIButton with constraints in a storyboard that looks like this.... with constraints to safe areas as well as a height/width constraint. the height constraint is set to 30

[image]

but the output looks like... (deff not 30 height and regardless of what I set as the height constraint it looks like the following) also the buttons other than Daily are not shown because they have no constraints yet!

[image]

here are the constraints

[image]

[image]

2019-03-04 01:43:35.157418-0500 Daily[831:112538] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this:

(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;

(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints 
and fix it

Comment: Are you using `UIStackView` there?

Comment: add constraint property screenshot which is you have set.

Comment: @iPeter checkout the new screenshot! thanks!

Comment: @AtulParmar ^^^

Comment: You can take the three buttons inside an `UIStackView` and then fix it's height.

Comment: @iPeter the issue is I want to animate all the buttons (differently) depending on which button is selected. when one is clicked it will grow and the others will move aside or up/down

Comment: Can you show the code you've written for animating the buttons?

Comment: @iPeter I haven't implemented them yet. I originally wasn't using auto-layout but I figure it's time to learn

Comment: Remove the bottom constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use unnecessary constraints as you were set both width and leading, trailing. You can check this by updating constraints as attached image.

Feel free to ask me if any problem

> *Remember, this is a sample button to guide you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this worked. Thank you very much I had too many constraints I guess? Weird that it stretches. I don't have a horrible understanding of auto-layout at the moment

Answer (score 3):

In this case, height and bottom constraint will conflict, I think you have set top, bottom, and height constraint property of `UIbutton`, So if you want fixed height 15 then remove the bottom constraint. and if you don't want fixed hight then keep as it is a bottom constraint and remove height constraint of `UIbutton`.

Answer (score 0):

Look for Constraints error/warning at runtime. If there is inconsistency, few constraints are removed during runtime.

Try setting vertical content hugging property - High. This will inform system, content does not want to grow.

[image]

Comment: added them. Also trying to remove a couple constraints as suggested

Comment: Height constraint and bottom constraint may create conflicts.